# git diff failing with "fatal: bad object $hash HEAD"

Tags: git

I am running a Jenkins job on a new node. Whether I clone the repository fresh or copy it from another working node, I get:

```
$ git diff --name-only 27b9a8a4b0269d3796defe00ff56eb835fd3d84b HEAD
fatal: bad object 27b9a8a4b0269d3796defe00ff56eb835fd3d84b
$
```

Following other answers on StackOverflow (most of which are about "bad object HEAD" rather than my situation "bad object $hash HEAD"), I have tried:

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (213374/213374), done.
$ git status
HEAD detached at b08bd7495
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git log --raw --all | fgrep 27b9a8a4b
$
```

The hash 27b9a8a4b... does not appear anywhere in the output from git log.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what the problem is, but I am sure that it's a Jenkins thing, not a Git thing. More precisely, your Jenkins has latched on to some hash ID that does not actually exist. Somehow you need to prod Jenkins into getting a good hash ID, whatever "good" may be for Jenkins, and to stop passing this wrong one through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa… I had duplicated a Jenkins job that referred to my own fork of the repository, but the repository I had first copied and then cloned by hand were of the main repository. Getting the correct repository in place solved the problem.

Comment: Good catch, more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case similar to "[Jenkins Invalid Git Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46045821/6309)", where the `lastBuiltRevision` memorized by Jenkins reference a non-existing SHA1.

That SHA1 might not exist anymore because of a `git push --force` of a new history replacing a previous one, rendering that particular SHA1 obsolete.